# cannot convert from 'DerivedClass *' to 'BaseClass *&'

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, pass-by-reference, upcasting

I try the following code, and get a compilation error.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

void f(A*& p) {}

int
main()
{
    B* pB;
    f(pB); // cannot convert argument 1 from 'B *' to 'A *&'

    return 0;
}
```

How to work around to make f(pB) call the f(A*&p) function?

Comment: My two cents, but it want get above the noise below. The reason you can't cast reference types like this is the same reason you can't cast pointer types like this. A** is a pointer to a pointer, B** is a pointer to a pointer. While you can cast B* to an A*, it doesn't mean you can cast the pointers to them. It is like trying to cast an `int32_t*` to a `uint32_t*`: just because you can cast an int32_t to a uint32_t (with no byte changes) their pointers loose that relationship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pointer variable passed to a non-`const` reference must match the same data type as the reference.  The function is expecting a reference to an `A*` pointer so that is what you have to give it.  If you have a `B*` pointer to start with, assign it to an `A*` variable first (since `B` derives from `A`):

```
B* pB = ...;
A* pA = pB;
f(pA);
```

But if the function modifies the pointer it is passed, it will modify `pA` not `pB`.  If you need it to modify `pB` instead, you will have to re-think your design.

If you qualify the parameter as `const`, thereby **guaranteeing** that `f` won't modify it, then there is no problem:

```
void f(A* const & p) { /* Compiles fine */ }
```

Comment: "The variable passed to a reference must match the same data type as the reference" that's not true in case of inheritance

Comment: It is true if the reference is not `const`, as in this example. If the reference were `const` then the compiler can implictly pass a derived class to a base class reference.

Comment: it is not true even without const qualifier. Consider this: http://pastebin.com/6fWr7z6h

Comment: what is the point of passing a non-const reference? he probably intended to modify the pointer

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this, and here's why. Suppose it was allowed and `f()` looked like this:

```
void f(A*& p) { p = new A(); }
```

Now you do this:

```
B* pB;
f(pB);
```

When `f()` returns, `pB` will be pointing to an `A`. Kaboom!

Answer (score 0):

In your code the function f takes "a pointer to class A by reference".
You cannot dynamically convert a "reference to a A-pointer" into a "reference to a B-pointer": while the B class is derived from the A class (and therefore a B-reference is dynamically converted into a A-reference) a B-pointer is still not a derived class of a A-pointer. Your attempt to mix pointers and references doesn't even make a lot of sense I think. 
You should simply modify your code into

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

void f( A & p) {}

int
main()
{
    B pB;
    f(pB); // you are now passing a B object by reference

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers explained very nicely why your code can't work.
If you want to have a nice workaround to your problem, you can use template function of foo:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    A(A*) {}
    virtual ~A() {}
};
class B : public A {
public:
    B () {}
    B(B*) {}
    virtual ~B() {}
};

template <class A, class B> 
B* foo(A* p) {
    //do something related to p - delete, or something
    B* p_new = new B(dynamic_cast <B*> (p));
    return p_new;
}
int
main()
{
    B* pB = new B;      
    pB = foo <A,B> (pB);
    return 0;
}
```